# Whitebox testing with break

Tags: java, testing, white-box-testing

Can someone tell me if my whitebox testing is correct? Can I put 2 arrows entering for statement 8 ?

Code being tested:

[image: Code being tested]

Whitebox test:

[image: Whitebox test]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your "whitebox testing" the diagramm that you have posted or what?

Comment: @lexicore yes the diagram

Comment: Do you want to draw a diagramm of all possible transitions between statements in your programm?

Comment: It is a whitebox testing diagram , I'm checking if my logic is correct

Comment: So do you want to draw a diagramm of all possible transitions between statements in your programm?

Comment: @lexicore sorry but without the image how would you know which line of code the other image is referring to?

Comment: You could tag then with inline comments.

Comment: @lexicore if you could help me with ,yes

Comment: @lexicore sorry I didn't know that I'm new to this forumn :)

Answer (score 0):

Below are all the possible transitions:

- 1 - 2
- 2 - 3
- 2 - 8 (`scheduling.cell.row` may be empty)
- 3 - 4
- 3 - 8 (`db.getvehicles` may be empty)
- 4 - 5
- 4 - 6
- 5 - 3
- 5 - 8
- 6 - 7
- 7 - 8

That's it. The whole 9-13 part is not executed here as it will be executed as a reaction on a drag event. So there is no direct connection between 8 and 9.